# Use awk to pull a very specific section out of a file

Tags: linux, awk, less, tomcat

I am trying to write a script (well, a one-liner really) to extract the important part of a debug log, so that people can easily send it to me instead of dragging me onto a conference call or having to collect the whole file. I can tell them what to do in less or vi to get the info, but I would like it as a command if possible.

In `less`:

```
$ less filename
G
?Server\ version
/SEVERE
[read line including first match for SEVERE from this point, stop reading when get to next instance of SEVERE]
```

I have been trying to write an `awk` command that will accomplish this, and it is not going well.

This is as close as I got that does not work:

```bsh
awk '{if (/Server version/) {chunk=""} else {chunk=chunk $0 RS}} END {printf "%s", chunk}'  filename | awk '/SEVERE/,/SEVERE/'
```

`awk` doesn't seem to like using the same pattern for the beginning and end of the part I want printed out at the end.

I am open to using other tools, but for my use case, I need to use utilities that come by default on RHEL7.

If the info helps at all, I am looking at apache tomcat debug logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to output the lines between the first and next occurrence of `SEVERE` after
the last occurrence of `Server version`.

Example input file:

```
Server version
SEVERE
ignore
SEVERE
Server version
ignore
SEVERE
important
stuff
SEVERE 
ignore
SEVERE
```

```
awk '
  /Server version/{ chunk="" }
  /SEVERE/{ logme=(chunk=="") }
  logme{ chunk=chunk $0 RS }
  END{ printf "%s", chunk }
' file
```

Output:

```
SEVERE
important
stuff
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly. Now I just have to study it a bit so I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-line outline:
Print line numbers with grep, extract them and use awk

`grep -n SEVERE filename | head -n 2 | cut -d ':' -f1`

This will output the first 2 line numbers [a, b] containing 'SEVERE' and awk could easily print the SEVERE and intervening lines...

`awk 'NR>=a && NR<=b {print $0;}' filename`

This could be easily scripted - but it requires a double pass through the log file.

Comment: not sure if I tried to follow this wrong, but I got no output on my example file:


$ grep -n SEVERE catalina.2021-01-19-210119205246.log | head -n 2 | cut -d ':' -f1
1
21

and then:


$ awk '1>=a && 21<=b {print $0;}' catalina.2021-01-19-210119205246.log

no output there.

Comment: The second statement should be awk 'NR>=1 && NR<=21 {print $0;}' catalina.2021-01-19-210119205246.log